# Purpose of remote: true in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed a rails tutorial where we submitted a form with ajax. We used `remote: true` in `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for @task, remote: true do |f|   %>
```

Everything works fine. But I'm confused about `remote: true`. What is the purpose of `remote: true`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**JS**

`remote: true` is a part of the [Rails UJS (unobtrusive Javascript)](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) driver. It just adds the `data-remote: true` attribute to any object you add it to, allowing Rails's UJS script to bind it to some ajax functionality...

[Some definition from Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for):

> Note the `data-remote="true"`. Now, the form will be submitted by Ajax
>   rather than by the browser's normal submit mechanism.
>
> You probably don't want to just sit there with a filled out ,
>   though. You probably want to do something upon a successful
>   submission. To do that, bind to the ajax:success event. On failure,
>   use ajax:error. Check it out:

[It's pretty simple really](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L108)....

[image]

It basically assigns a Javascript `.on` bind to any elements on your page which have `data-remote: true`. This is what sends the Ajax request for you.

---

**Hooks**

The important thing to note is that this method creates [several "hooks"](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) which you can use with your other javascript:

[image]

This allows you to use the `remote: true` functionality, and customise what happens by using the hooks above...

```
#app/views/messages/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @messages, remote: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#messages", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    alert("Form submitted, thank you!");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`remote: true` generates `data-remote="true"` as html

It submits `form` by `ajax` rather than browser's normal submit mechanism

[Reference](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for)

Answer (score 2):

`:remote => true` flag is used on the link or form tag in your view file for the element that you want to trigger the ***AJAX*** call, e.g.

```
<%= form_for @task, remote: true do |f| %>
```

with `:remote => true`, Rails **will not** automatically switch views, which allows the JQuery to be run instead.

The main purpose of using  `:remote => true` with the form is, the form is submitted by Ajax rather than by the browser's normal submit mechanism.

I highly recommend you to read the [Official Rails Documentation for Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).
There you will find some examples of using `:remote => true` with forms, links etc which will help you understand the purpose of `:remote=true` in Rails :-)

Comment: it is easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

`remote: true` allows to submit a form or simply to generate a request without refreshing the page

You can use remote: true with links as well
The best example of remote form submission is when you upvote/downvote an answer on stackoverflow